# ConText under Windows

Tags: context, editors, texniccenter, text

I'm very frustrated by the fact that almost all ConText documentations are **outdated**. For example, I followed the steps in ConText Garden Wiki's "Adapting TeXnicCenter for processing ConTeXt documents" but those steps didn't work. I'm using **Windows 10**. 
I tried the SCiTe editor following the instructions, but didn't work either.

Is there any up-to-date guide (step by step for a novice like me) under Windows about how to configure **ANY text editor** to get a pdf using ConText?

If anyone uses ConText under windows, please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try just installing TeX Live and using any old editor plus the command line? I can happily run ConTeXt MkIV on Windows either from the command line or in TeXworks (a very 'light weight' front end).

Comment: The contextgarden page about texniccenter it really *very* outdated. Nowadays you call context with "context file", and you don't need perl, ruby etc.

Comment: I am able to run context mkiv on windows either from the command line or in TeXnic Center. I followed the instruction given Contextgarden page. In Texnic center you have to go to Build >> Define Output profile and in profiles tab copy any of the existing and rename as context-->pdf  and then go to viewer tab and give your pdf reader path in the executable path and in both command text box add "%bm.pdf" and click the ok button.

Comment: @murugan Could you be more elaborate about Texnic center configuration? What did you put in command line arguments in Output profile?  I don't know what you mean by "copy any of the existing". Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried compiling using the command line?

Comment: @Aditya Yes, I finally succeeded in compilation using the command line. However, do I have to type "C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\context\tex\setuptex.bat" EVERY TIME when I want to compile because "context" command is not recognized once I quit the command line. Not convenient. Thanks.

Comment: Depends on your overall setup. Do you also have a latex installation? If not, you ca add context to your path. Otherwise you can create a shortcut with the initialization as described in [the wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Standalone#Usage_2). Another option is to create a `.bat` wrapper that calls setup tex for you.

Comment: @Aditya I have a latex installation (Tex-live). I will try to make a .bat file. Anyway thank you very much for your help and have a wonderful week.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Click Define Output Profiles menu

[image]

Now copy existing Latex--> PDF menu

[image]

Then change Latex to Context --> PDF and press ok

[image]
Now go to viewer tab and give path to your PDF VIEWER and command text box as shown in the picture

[image]

Now click OK and start working.